# Detect double tap on previous track button of remote control on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

How to detect double tap on previous track button of remote control on iPhone?

I'm able to detect double taps on view and button of app, but UNABLE to detect double tap on button in the Remote Control (previous button in multitasking bar)..

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot detect the touches of the OS itself, in your case the multitasking bar. You can only detect touches within the bounds of your app. When the multitasking bar is revealed by the user, your application calls the 
    `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method